# Ошибка «invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table»

Tags: sql, postgresql

Имеется простейший код:

```sql
SELECT t.id FROM t AS u;
```

Получаю ошибку «*invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table
"t"*».  В чём дело?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При использовании синонимов (англ. «*alias*»), в запросе нужно
использовать только их.  Из
[документации](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM)
(выделение добавлено):

> A substitute name for the `FROM` item containing the alias.
> An alias is used for brevity or to eliminate ambiguity for self-joins
> (where the same table is scanned multiple times). **When an alias
> is provided, it completely hides the actual name of the table or
> function;** for example given `FROM foo AS f`, the
> remainder of the `SELECT` must refer to this
> `FROM` item as `f` not `foo`. If an
> alias is written, a column alias list can also be written to provide
> substitute names for one or more columns of the table.